# MySQL scheme for opengeocode.org database COW

Tags: mysql

I want to import the "Countries of the World" database of opengeocode.org into a MySQL database to extend it by postal addressing format information. Is there a database scheme public available?

http://opengeocode.org/download/cow.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a great database of information, would be great if they had it in MySQL format.

Anyway just in case anyone else comes across this page, here's what I did to import the data.  I didn't spend hours on this, so might need some tweaking but should get you well on the way.  You might need to tweak the number of header lines if they change the comments in the future.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS countries_of_the_world ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries_of_the_world (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ISO3166a2 CHAR(2) NOT NULL ,
  ISO3166a3 CHAR(3) NULL ,
  ISO3166n3 INT(3) NULL ,
  FIPS104 CHAR(2) NULL ,
  ISOen_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  ISOen_proper VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  ISOen_ro_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  ISOen_ro_proper VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  ISOfr_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  ISOfr_proper VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  ISOes_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNen_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNen_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNfr_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNfr_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNes_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNes_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNru_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNru_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNlc_ro_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNlc_ro_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  BGN_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  BGN_proper VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  BGN_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  BGNlc_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  BGNlc_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PCGN_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PCGN_proper VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PCGN_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  FAOit_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  FAOit_proper VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  FAOit_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  EKI_name VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  EKI_longname VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  conabbr VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  HasCapital TINYINT NULL ,
  BGN_capital VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNGEGNlc_capital VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNen_capital VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNfr_capital VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNes_capital VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  UNru_capital VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  EKI_capital VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  BGNc_latitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  BGNc_longitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  UNc_latitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  UNc_longitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  continent CHAR(2) NULL ,
  subcontinent CHAR(2) NULL ,
  ISOregion SMALLINT NULL ,
  ISOsubregion SMALLINT NULL ,
  language VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  population INT NULL ,
  year SMALLINT NULL ,
  BGN_demonym VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  BGN_demonym_adj VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  ITU SMALLINT NULL ,
  IVC VARCHAR(3) NULL ,
  land INT NULL ,
  water INT NULL ,
  land_total INT NULL ,
  latitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  longitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  maxlatitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  minlatitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  minlongitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  maxlongitude DOUBLE NULL ,
  url_gov VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  url_stats VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  url_gis VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  url_post VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) )
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/cow.txt'
INTO TABLE countries_of_the_world
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '; ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 29 LINES
(
  ISO3166a2,
  ISO3166a3,
  ISO3166n3,
  FIPS104,
  ISOen_name,
  ISOen_proper,
  ISOen_ro_name,
  ISOen_ro_proper,
  ISOfr_name,
  ISOfr_proper,
  ISOes_name,
  UNGEGNen_name,
  UNGEGNen_longname,
  UNGEGNfr_name,
  UNGEGNfr_longname,
  UNGEGNes_name,
  UNGEGNes_longname,
  UNGEGNru_name,
  UNGEGNru_longname,
  UNGEGNlc_ro_name,
  UNGEGNlc_ro_longname,
  BGN_name,
  BGN_proper,
  BGN_longname,
  BGNlc_longname,
  BGNlc_name,
  PCGN_name,
  PCGN_proper,
  PCGN_longname,
  FAOit_name,
  FAOit_proper,
  FAOit_longname,
  EKI_name,
  EKI_longname,
  conabbr,
  HasCapital,
  BGN_capital,
  UNGEGNlc_capital,
  UNen_capital,
  UNfr_capital,
  UNes_capital,
  UNru_capital,
  EKI_capital,
  BGNc_latitude,
  BGNc_longitude,
  UNc_latitude,
  UNc_longitude,
  continent,
  subcontinent,
  ISOregion,
  ISOsubregion,
  language,
  population,
  year,
  BGN_demonym,
  BGN_demonym_adj,
  ITU,
  IVC,
  land,
  water,
  land_total,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  maxlatitude,
  minlatitude,
  minlongitude,
  maxlongitude,
  url_gov,
  url_stats,
  url_gis,
  url_post
);
```